# Handle a directive exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, import, directive

I have a code where it uses #import to get a .dll from somewhere in the computer. Now I'm supposed to use the program in computers that either have this file, or doesn't. It won't even compile if it doesn't have the file, so is there something I can do, similar o a try catch throw?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The `#import` directive is used to get a type library that defines COM interfaces. Presumably your program uses these COM interfaces, getting them for example using the `CoCreateInstance` function. You need to check the return value from CoCreateInstance to see if the COM object was succesfully generated; if not, you can throw any exception that you want.

Comment: How can I get it to compile without the file?

Comment: @Jason, you have to compile on a machine that has the file, then you can move the compiled .exe to one that doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you would normally handle in the installed - set the dll to be a mandatory dependency of the application, and perhaps include it in the distribution.